# Dynamic User Controls

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, user-controls

I am new in `WPF` and want to add the buttons on the base of SQL-Query like in ASP.Net `ListView`. I want to make buttons on the base of record in `DataTable` dynamically. What should i use? And What will be the code behind?

```cs
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from tblGroup", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

}
```

Comment: Questions like _"What should i use?"_ is offtopic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

First create a model for your output.

Then create an observable collection of your model as property in your code behind

```
public ObservableCollection<YourModel> Collection { get; private set; }    

public Window() {
    Collection = GetYourData();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

After that you can bind it to a DataGrid like this

```
<DataGrid x:Name="YourTable" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=YourWindow, Path=Collection}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Example" Binding="{Binding ModelProperty}"/>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Your Button">
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <Button Content="Your Button">
                        <Button.Style>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourDependingModelProperty}" Value="YourDesiredValue">
                                         <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                         <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="YourClickEvent"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                    <!-- You can add more triggers here -->
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Button.Style>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This code is untested but might be worth a shot for you